# SSIS - Conditional Precedence Constraint Flow and Connection Validation

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a conditional branch of the execution tree in SSIS (enable/disable using parameter). Largely because certain servers are unavailable at certain times. However, when I run my package (even with dalay validation), it tries to validate the connection in the part of the package that is not suppose to run and fails.

Is there a good/easy setting that can do this? If the task is disabled, will it still try to validate?

Comment: do you have delay validation set to true on the connection objects as well?

Comment: Also set the delay validation to true at the package level

Comment: Setting delay validation at the package level did it! Thank you.